# Test Copy-on-write in swift

Tags: swift, copy-on-write

```
 import Foundation

 func address(o:UnsafeRawPointer) -> Int {
     return Int(bitPattern: o)
 }
 var originArray = [1,2,3]
 var firstArray = originArray


//q.append(4)
print(NSString.init(format: "originArray:%p", address(o: &originArray)))
print(NSString.init(format: "firstArray:%p", address(o: &firstArray)))
```

**Debug Log:
originArray:0x100b087b0
firstArray:0x100b088c0**

Above, it's my test code.I think that I don't modify originArray which like appending or reduceing element. they should point same address.but why deference

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is printing the addresses of the array buffers (`Array` [is a special case](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6) when passing a value to a pointer parameter). However, in Swift 3, the compiler assumed that the presence of the `&` operator meant that the buffer was being passed as *mutable* memory, so (unnecessarily) made it unique (by copying) before passing its pointer value, despite that pointer value being passed as an `UnsafeRawPointer`. That's why you see different addresses.

If you remove the `&` operator and pass the arrays directly:

```
func address(_ p: UnsafeRawPointer) {
    print(p)
}

var originArray = [1, 2, 3]
var firstArray = originArray

address(originArray) // 0x00000000016e71c0
address(firstArray)  // 0x00000000016e71c0
```

You'll now get the same addresses, as the compiler now assumes that `address(_:)` will not modify the memory of the buffers passed, as they're being passed to an `UnsafeRawPointer` parameter.

In Swift 4, this inconsistency is fixed, and the compiler no longer makes the buffer unique before passing its pointer values to an `UnsafeRawPointer` parameter, even when using the `&` operator, so your code exhibits expected behaviour.

Although, it's worth noting that the above method isn't *guaranteed* to produce stable pointer values when passing the same array to multiple pointer parameters.

From the Swift blog post "[Interacting with C Pointers](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=6)":

> Even if you pass the same variable, array, or string as multiple pointer arguments, you could receive a different pointer each time.

I *believe* this guarantee cannot be met for arrays in two cases (there may be more):

1. **If the array is viewing elements in non-contiguous storage**

   Swift's `Array` can view elements in non-contiguous storage, for example when it is wrapping an `NSArray`. In such a case, when passing it to a pointer parameter, a *new* contiguous buffer will have to be created, therefore giving you a different pointer value.
2. **If the buffer is non-uniquely referenced when passed as mutable memory**

   As mentioned earlier, when passing an array to a mutable pointer parameter, its buffer will first be made unique in order to preserve value semantics, as it's assumed the function will perform a mutation of the buffer.

   Therefore, if the buffer was copied, you'll get a different pointer value to if you had passed the array to an immutable pointer parameter.

Although neither of these two points are applicable in the example you give, it's worth bearing in mind that the compiler still *doesn't* guarantee you stable pointer values to the array's buffer when passing to pointer parameters.

For results that are guaranteed to be reliable, you should use the [`withUnsafeBytes(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray/2634965-withunsafebytes) method on a [`ContiguousArray`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray):

```
var originArray: ContiguousArray = [1, 2, 3]
var firstArray = originArray

originArray.withUnsafeBytes { print($0.baseAddress!) } // 0x0000000102829550
firstArray.withUnsafeBytes { print($0.baseAddress!) }  // 0x0000000102829550
```

This is because [`withUnsafeBytes(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray/2634965-withunsafebytes) is documented as accepting:

> A closure with an `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` parameter that points to the contiguous storage for the array. If no such storage exists, it is created.

And [`ContiguousArray`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/contiguousarray) guarantees that:

> [it] always stores its elements in a contiguous region of memory

And just like `Array`, `ContiguousArray` uses copy-on-write in order to have value semantics, so you can still use it to check when the array's buffer is copied upon a mutation taking place:

```
var originArray: ContiguousArray = [1, 2, 3]
var firstArray = originArray

originArray.withUnsafeBytes { print($0.baseAddress!) } // 0x0000000103103eb0
firstArray.withUnsafeBytes { print($0.baseAddress!) }  // 0x0000000103103eb0

firstArray[0] = 4

originArray.withUnsafeBytes { print($0.baseAddress!) } // 0x0000000103103eb0
firstArray.withUnsafeBytes { print($0.baseAddress!) }  // 0x0000000100e764d0
```

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the address of the variable itself, not the address of the array buffer it's pointing to.

You can get the address of the arrays' buffers like so:

```
var originArray = [1, 2, 3]
var firstArray = originArray

print("originArray: \(originArray.withUnsafeBytes { $0.baseAddress! })")
print("firstArray:  \(firstArray.withUnsafeBytes { $0.baseAddress! })")
```

Now the same value is printed, unless you modify one of the arrays.

Comment: What's your meanings and how to print address of buffer

Comment: Can I get a buffer of struct when copy-on-write and how

Comment: You can access the array's underlying buffer using the unsafe functions listed [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array) under the "Accessing Underlying Storage" subtitle.

Comment: @Hamish do you meanings that If the  `array` changed ,address of `array` buffer should be no change until being passed as an `UnsafeRawPointer `
and  the blow (now deleted) answer is bug in swift3?

Comment: @Buer I added an answer, which I hope answers your question – do let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: @Hamish  My English is not good,I spended some time  reading your answer and understood. your answer is perfect. Thanks again!